# Error al colocar un WHEN en consulta SQL - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo una consulta en oracle:

```
WITH hist_snaps
            AS (SELECT instance_number,
            snap_id,
            round(begin_interval_time,'MI') datetime,
            (  begin_interval_time + 0 - LAG (begin_interval_time + 0)
            OVER (PARTITION BY dbid, instance_number ORDER BY snap_id)) * 86400 diff_time
            FROM dba_hist_snapshot), hist_stats
            AS (SELECT dbid,
            instance_number,
            snap_id,
            stat_name,
            VALUE - LAG (VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY dbid,instance_number,stat_name ORDER BY snap_id)
            delta_value
            FROM dba_hist_sysstat
            WHERE stat_name IN ('user commits', 'user rollbacks'))
            SELECT datetime,
            ROUND (SUM (delta_value) / 3600, 2) as transactions
            FROM hist_snaps sn, hist_stats st, DUAL
            WHERE     st.instance_number = sn.instance_number
            AND st.snap_id = sn.snap_id
            AND datetime >= CURRENT_DATE - 1
            AND diff_time IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY datetime
            ORDER BY 1
```

Esto me retorna 2 columnas asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy tratando de hacer un WHEN para que cuando el dato que esta en transactions sea < 0 me coloque 0 en esa celda.

Trate con este codigo pero me da error:

```
WITH hist_snaps
            AS (SELECT instance_number,
            snap_id,
            round(begin_interval_time,'MI') datetime,
            (  begin_interval_time + 0 - LAG (begin_interval_time + 0)
            OVER (PARTITION BY dbid, instance_number ORDER BY snap_id)) * 86400 diff_time
            FROM dba_hist_snapshot), hist_stats
            AS (SELECT dbid,
            instance_number,
            snap_id,
            stat_name,
            VALUE - LAG (VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY dbid,instance_number,stat_name ORDER BY snap_id)
            delta_value
            FROM dba_hist_sysstat
            WHERE stat_name IN ('user commits', 'user rollbacks'))
            SELECT datetime,
            CASE ROUND (SUM (delta_value) / 3600, 2) as transactions1
                WHEN transactions1 < 0 THEN 0
            END AS transactions
            FROM hist_snaps sn, hist_stats st, DUAL
            WHERE     st.instance_number = sn.instance_number
            AND st.snap_id = sn.snap_id
            AND datetime >= CURRENT_DATE - 1
            AND diff_time IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY datetime
            ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no se puede utilizar el resultado del alias en la misma consulta, intenta esto:

```
WITH hist_snaps
            AS (SELECT instance_number,
            snap_id,
            round(begin_interval_time,'MI') datetime,
            (  begin_interval_time + 0 - LAG (begin_interval_time + 0)
            OVER (PARTITION BY dbid, instance_number ORDER BY snap_id)) * 86400 diff_time
            FROM dba_hist_snapshot), hist_stats
            AS (SELECT dbid,
            instance_number,
            snap_id,
            stat_name,
            VALUE - LAG (VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY dbid,instance_number,stat_name ORDER BY snap_id)
            delta_value
            FROM dba_hist_sysstat
            WHERE stat_name IN ('user commits', 'user rollbacks'))
            SELECT datetime,
            CASE 
            WHEN ROUND (SUM (delta_value) / 3600, 2) < 0 THEN 0
            END AS transactions
            FROM hist_snaps sn, hist_stats st, DUAL
            WHERE     st.instance_number = sn.instance_number
            AND st.snap_id = sn.snap_id
            AND datetime >= CURRENT_DATE - 1
            AND diff_time IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY datetime
            ORDER BY 1
```